# php code to update date using +1 months from forloop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
input data from form like below.

receipt      =  700
coupon       =  501,502,503,504,505,506
coupondate   =  28-02-2015
```

DATA in my table like below

**i need to update coupon and coupondate based on receipt....**

```
receipt    coupon  coupondate
 700        501    27-03-2015
 700        502    27-04-2015
 700        503    27-05-2015
 700        504    27-06-2015
 700        505    27-07-2015
 700        506    27-08-2015
```

but after update code runs this produce output like below....

```
receipt    coupon  coupondate
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
 700        501     27-03-2015
```

MY for loop  not working in update code ...plz help to generate proper output...

below is my update code....

BUT same code in insert query working well...but inh update it produce same output in all rows.....

plz help..

```
 if(isset ($_GET['edit']))
 {
    $receipt_no = $_GET['edit'];
    $coupon = $_POST['coupon'];                     
    $arr = explode(",", $coupon);
    $min = min($arr);
    $max = max($arr);   
    $startingdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['startingdate']));

    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= count($arr) ; $i++)  
    {
        $count = 1;
        for ($j = $min; $j <= $max; $j++)
        {

            $coupondate = date("d-m-Y", 
                               strtotime(date("d-m-Y", 
                                 strtotime($startingdate)) . 
                                 " +" . $count . " month - 1days"));
            $count++;                   
            $updaterow = $database->updateRow(
                         "UPDATE receipt_entry 
                          SET 
                          coupondate=:coupondate,
                          coupon=:coupon,
                          startingdate=:startingdate 
                          WHERE receipt_no = :receipt_no",
                                array(':coupondate'=>$coupondate,
                                      ':coupon'=>$j,
                                      ':startingdate'=>$startingdate,
                                      ':startingdate'=>$startingdate,
                                      ':receipt_no'=>$receipt_no
                                     )
                          );        
        }   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query says `WHERE receipt_no = :receipt_no` so it will always put the same data in ALL your rows that have that receipt_no. You need to specify exactly which row should be updated.

By the way, you have 2 nested for loops while you only want 1 for loop.